# Creating a VSCode extension for the search blade

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to create a VSCode extension that would allow me to display the search results of global search (ctrl shift f) in a tree view just like webstorm does it.
Unfortunately didn't find any extensions that would do similar.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's currently not possible to create an extension like that. You may open a feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: Yes, if you have a specific scenario in mind, please open a feature request. I work on vscode and am curious what you would want to do with an extension like this.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it won't be possible.. I downloaded the vs code source and I'll try to contribute with a feature. The only reason one of my colleague prefers WebStorm over VSCode is that it shows the search results in a tree structure. So I thought I'll challenge myself making it :) I'm thinking just a simple configuration in the settings json or a button in the search panel that would just switch the view. But first I need get my environment up for VSCode contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that it's not possible, I opened a feature request
[feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20224)
on their github